# What http status codes should I return for the following situations in my API

Tags: php, android, api, http

I am now developing the API for my android app and up until now I was using response codes like 1, 2 3 4 and so on without any convention.

I was looking at this article
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses'

but I cant quite figure out which codes should I use for the following situations:

- if the API call is invalid
- if the API call is empty
- if the API call is using the wrong method (POST instead of GET)
- if there is an error in the API itself (badly written code, unhandled situations, unforseen situations, PDO errors) resulting in a PDO exception or an error
- if there is an empty set of data returned (I consider that a success- if you are searching for "asjkdhaksjdh" its normal that you get no results) (maybe return 304?)
- if I am trying to register a user but the email is already taken

Comment: look at this: http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/655c1be6jw1ebnyg5ce13j20c85tge4i.jpg

Comment: this is quite nice :) but as I said I am not sure which codes correspond to the cases I've listed above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - if the API call is invalid
> - if the API call is empty
> - if the API call is using the wrong method (POST instead of GET)

**400 - Bad Request**

> - if there is an error in the API itself (badly written code, unhandled situations, unforseen situations, PDO errors) resulting in a PDO exception or an error

**500 - Internal Server Error**

> if there is an empty set of data returned (I consider that a success- if you are searching for "asjkdhaksjdh" its normal that you get no results)

Should be **404 Not Found**, however if you want to treat it like success, use **200 - OK**

> - if I am trying to register a user but the email is already taken

**403 - Forbidden** with message explaining why this request was not successful.